Segmentation problem
I have a segmentation problem with OTB implemented in QGIS 3.36. Indeed, I corrected the Landsat 8 image on ArcGIS and used pansharpening to improve the resolution. Then, I created a composite image at 15 m resolution. However, once in QGIS, the MeanShift segmentation process blocked and displays the following message:

(WARNING) Segmentation: The input image has no data values but this application does not handle no-data. No-data pixels will be treated as regular pixels.

knowing that I've used this composite on ArcGIS to calculate NDVI and NDWI.
Here's the message I get:

How can I proceed?

This question is similar to: Orfeo Toolbox error. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
